# How to replace fragments in activity

Tags: android, kotlin

I have `MainActivity` which has navigation bar including 4 buttons, I want to replace fragments in my `MainActivity` based on clicked button in navigation bar.

## Code

`activity_main.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.ismaeldivita.chipnavigation.ChipNavigationBar
        android:id="@+id/chipNavigationBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:background="#fff"
        android:padding="8dp"
        app:cnb_menuResource="@menu/bottom_menu"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />


    <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
        android:id="@+id/fragment"
        android:name="com.my.app.HomeFragment"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/chipNavigationBar"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        tools:ignore="MissingConstraints"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="125dp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`MainActivity.kt`

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val menu by lazy { findViewById<ChipNavigationBar>(R.id.chipNavigationBar) }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        // Fragments
        menu.setItemSelected(R.id.home)

        // USING: https://github.com/ismaeldivita/chip-navigation-bar
        menu.setOnItemSelectedListener { id ->
            menu.setItemSelected(id)
        }
        // End of Fragments
    }
}
```

#### Explanation

```
// in XML
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/fragment"
            android:name="com.my.app.HomeFragment" // set default fragment onCreate

// in MainActivity
menu.setItemSelected(R.id.home) // set default active nav item
```

## Question

Now my app onCreate will load default fragment for item 1 of my navigation, my question is how do I set other fragments for other 3 buttons in my navigation? (also) item 1 should be set to this default fragment in case `let say` user wants to back from item 3 to item 1.

**Any idea?**

Comment: maybe you can add some `when` operator whose cases will be assigned to the certain fragments and that make transition?

Comment: @Andrew would you show me how? also I'm not sure how should I call the fragment names in order to set them into `id` of `setOnItemSelectedListener`

Comment: I have posted some example) can you try it? I used similar way for my bottomNavigationView so I think you can use it too :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm speaking about such contruction:

```
menu.setOnItemSelectedListener { id ->
        val transaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()

        when (id) {
            R.id.your_id-> {
                transaction.replace(R.id.contentContainer, YourFrag()).commit()
            }

           ...
        }
    }
```

So, you will handle selected id and than make transactions to the fragments.

Comment: do you have such ids?

Comment: can you check via logs which id is selected in the listener, I'm asking about textual representation?

Comment: Ok, I just cleared caches it's indexing again after that I'll check and let you know

Comment: I don't sure whether cache clearing will help, but maybe)

Comment: There was `import android.R` caused all those issues, Thank you it's working now.